# Image to Text OCR Web Image URL Upload

Tags: javascript, html, css, ocr

referring to a working **codepen demo** at [here](https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/poZLrRm?editors=1010), the app is working fine if **choose file button clicked** which upload image from local computer  and the text from the image is extracted. However, how do I upload a **Web Image URL such as [this](https://i.ibb.co/T8ZhGjr/num.jpg) and not from local computer files** and with the help of **a button** which I labelled in my demo to output the OCR text result?

I would appreciate any help I can get :)

`<div class="content extra"><input id="file" type="file" onchange="proccess(window.lastFile=this.files[0])"></div>`

I have tried to change the onchange to onclick but does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an input like that :

```html
<div class="content extra">
  <input id="file" type="file" onchange="proccess(window.lastFile=this.files[0])">
</div>
<div class="content extra">
  <label for="imgURL">Or paste image url : </label>
  <input id="imgURL" type="text" onchange="proccess(value)">
</div>
```

And check in your process function if the param is a string or not, if it is it means we have an URL so we just defined this url as src value :

```js
function proccess(inputData){
  $(".result").html("");
  var src;
  if(typeof(inputData) == 'string') {
    src = inputData
  } else {
    src = (window.URL ? URL : webkitURL).createObjectURL(inputData);
  }
  //do what you want after that...
  //...
}
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the answer, I have created a new demo with your code at https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/XWBYVbo?editors=1010   , am I doing it right because I am not getting any output haha? Sorry, I am really pretty new to Javascript.

Comment: you missed the function declaration you wrote `function proccess(file)` instead of `function proccess(inputData)`

Comment: You also need to replace `file` by `inputData` on line 12 (` Tesseract.recognize(file)`)

Comment: Hi, I have updated my demo, its real-time haha :), the image displays but it does not display the output when I click on the After Pasting URL button?